# How to Custom group notify for blocks of functions

Tags: ios, iphone, block

> Asynchronous block be called in function, add these multiple functions into a group,process all results of blocks when all block execute completely.Is there a common and smart method to implement?
>   like dispatch_group_notify ,completionBlock

[image: example]

[image: dispatch_group_notify]

[image: NSBlockOperation]

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_group_t _blockTaskGroup;
.....

if (!_blockTaskGroup) {
    _blockTaskGroup = dispatch_group_create();
}

dispatch_group_notify(_blockTaskGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"finally!");
});

....

dispatch_group_enter(_blockTaskGroup);
[XXXXX computeInBackground:xx completion:^{
    NSLog(@"1 done");
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];
//
dispatch_group_enter(_blockTaskGroup);
[XXXXX computeInBackground:xx completion:^{
    NSLog(@"2 done");
    dispatch_group_leave(_blockTaskGroup);
}];
//
dispatch_group_enter(_blockTaskGroup);
[XXXXX computeInBackground:xx completion:^{
    NSLog(@"3 done");
    dispatch_group_leave(_blockTaskGroup);
}];
```